# Ubuntu Detects my usb modem (made by samsung) as a cellphone (galaxy S III) is there a way around this

Tags: 14.04, mobile-broadband

I plugged in my Mobile Broadband device and it brought up a window saying it couldn't connect phone, my question is if there is a way to get around this and connect it as my internet (Samsung Galaxy S II, S III and Tab 10.1 is what comes up with lsusb) it detects all other things as they should be

Comment: Please provide the device identification. eg. output from **`lsusb`** that is different with the device present.

Comment: @david6 I added the information you requested

Comment: Sorry, the USB ID e.g, **04e8:????** *Can you also identify the model of modem.*